# How to know data type of result of evaluation based on a schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a an sql expression and input schema type. Based on these two information it seems possible to deduct the result type when the expression is applied to a data frame with the schema. How can I know result type without explicitly creating a data frame with the given schema.

I basically want to complete following method:

```
def resultType(sqlExpression: String, schema: StructType): DataType = {

}
```

One way to achieve it is:

```
def createEmptyDataFrame(schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val dummyRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row.empty))
    spark.createDataFrame(dummyRDD, schema)
}

def resultType(sqlExpression: String, schema: StructType): DataType = {
    val df = createEmptyDataFrame(schema)
    val result = df.withColumn("temp", expr(sqlExpression))
    result.schema("temp").dataType
}
```

> How can achieve the same without creating an empty dataframe?